# Keyclock-gatekeeper/louketo-proxy events not propagating to all clients immediately

Tags: realm, single-sign-on, keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper

I am using Keycloak as an IAM and have clients "alertmanager" and "Nginx" which are running along with Keycloak-gatekeeper/louketo-proxy as a sidecar in my K8s cluster. Users are able to login perfectly but getting some issues with logout.

When I try to "Logout all" under "Session" from the Keycloak admin section. I get this error and parallelly the gatekeeper/proxy gets a call from Keycloack(I am checking live logs) but since this very request is unauthenticated so that request fails. So, how can we whitelist the IP address of keycloak here?

[image]

**Also**, how can we propagate logout to all the clients from browser when one of the client(application) performs a logout by hitting application/**oauth/logout** in the browser? The other application which has also logged via SSO in the same browser previously is **not logged out and token still persists tokens**(checked via application2/oauth/token), both clients(applications) are from the same realm.

It's taking a maximum of 5 mins to refresh among different clients when the proxy asks keycloak to refresh the token.

When I add/remove a user from a particular group let's say "devops" and the proxy/gatekeeper is configured to give access where the user is present in the group "devops". So, if I add someone in the "devops" group it'll maximum of 5 mins to reflect that, and users can start using the associated application. **But, when I remove a user from the group. They can still enjoy the access of "devops" group for a maximum of 5 mins, which is a security concern!**

**Is there a way to propagate events from Keycloack to all the clients instantly.
Is this expected behavior of Keycloack?**